# Creating a form with transparent PNG as background in c#

Tags: c#, forms, background, png, transparent

i want to create a transparent form with png as background... which looks verymuch similar to this.

http://cdn.lo4d.com/t/screenshot/800/lili-usb-creator-3.jpg

so far i've used this code

```
    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(this.BackgroundImage, e.ClipRectangle);
    }
```

but the problem is when moving the part below doesnt update!!

i tried to use

```
invalidate();
```

but it keeps on drawing the image over and over making the dropshadow part denser and denser.

is there anything i can do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this one works great.not very neat but it works upto the mark.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19213/An-Alpha-Channel-Composited-Windows-Form-with-Desi